# Getting error 405 upon submitting a delete request with axio

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-delete

I have a DELETE request which I have tested and works with POSTMAN.

```
localhost:5000/api/flavour/5e3feb54e896ab7c00437f0a.
```

I've even tried passing params for the 2nd parameter in axio layer. but it became ( I would get 404 )
    localhost:5000/api/flavour/?id=5e3feb54e896ab7c00437f0a.

However, how can I do that on UI side with axio ? I have tried hardcoded the url for testing,but it doesn't work.

This is my axio code. (Currently keep on getting 405)

```
DeleteFlavour: async (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    let res = await axios.delete('/api/flavour/{id}');
    console.log(res);
    return res.data || [];
  }
```

And this is my route

```
app.delete(`/api/flavour/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    const {id} = req.params;

    let flavour = await Flavour.findByIdAndDelete(id);

    return res.status(202).send({
      error: false,
      flavour
    })
  })
```

Comment: This can possibly be a CORS issue. Check if you have enabled CORS on your server side code.

Comment: Hi @MadhuBhat, i solved it by hardcoding my endpoint to localhost:5000. If there is no such hardcode, i found that it's sending to port 3000 *client* and therefore that explains why i'm getting 405. Can I know how can i remove the hardcode endpoint ?. GET & POST request doesn't require any port number tho... they can GET n POST successfully. So im not sure why DELETE needs the http://localhost:5000/api/flavour/5e3254501 ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you have typo resulting in wrong url. You have:

```
let res = await axios.delete('/api/flavour/{id}');
```

It should probably be:

```
let res = await axios.delete('/api/flavour/' + id);
```

Or

```
let res = await axios.delete(`/api/flavour/${id}`);
```

Comment: Hi kaliatech. I've tried all three of them. Still getting 405 error code. However if i use POSTMAN to do a DELETE, that url route works.